What can I use to temporarily fill a divot in a laminate counter top?
I have a chunk missing from the edge of my Formica counter top that I would like to repair if possible. It doesn’t have to be pretty because I plan to cover the counters temporarily until I can afford to replace them. What’s the best thing to use?


What's your goal if you don't care how it looks and it's temporary anyway?

Do you still have the chip?

You can use a synthetic wood filler to level out the divot.
